# I am trying to loop through a list of groups using get-adgroupmember, but i want my results in a table format

Tags: powershell

```
$groups = gc H:\Groups.txt
        Foreach ($group in $groups) {
            Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | ft $group

            }
```

This is what i have been trying, but that only list users and not what group they are a member of.

Thanks Alex

Answer (score 3):

Not tested but is this the sort of thing you are after:

```
$groups = gc H:\Groups.txt

$report = @()
Foreach ($group in $groups) {
  Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | % {
    $report += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      Group = $group
      Name = $_.name
    }
  }
}
$report | ft -Autosize
```

Comment: Yeap, That is exactly what im am looking for, works a treat.... don't suppose you could give a quick explanation of what you did there for someone new to powershell... no rush...... :-)